# How can I play mp2 or any other codec in HTML5 player or any other javascript player

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a specific need to stream content from a URL using JavaScript and JWPlayer. However, JWPlayer lacks support for the MP2 codec. Is there a way to enable playback using a browser extension or an alternative module?